# How many entities do I have in my model?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I'm wondering how I can find the number of entities in my model. Any idea?

Comment: Count them and you will know ;-)  What exactly is your problem?

Comment: Do you mean the number of entity definitions or the number of entity instances?

Comment: @lazarus: number of entity definitions

Comment: @Reza I'm guessing you are working on a database-first EF implementation, is that why you need to know this and why you don't already know this?

Comment: it's not equivalent with number of tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened the edmx as xml, and searched csdl for `<EntityType` and get count using a word processor. That's it!

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve [information about your Entity Data Model programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387116.aspx) by using the [MetadataWorkspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.metadataworkspace.aspx) class, which is available through the [ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.metadataworkspace.aspx) property:

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext
var metadata = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace;

var entityCount = metadata.GetItems(DataSpace.OSpace).Count;
```

The [DataSpace.OSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.dataspace.aspx) enumeration value instructs the [MetadataWorkspace.GetItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738668.aspx) method to return the number of items found in the **object model space** of the EDM.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EF model first, open Server Explorer -> Click on your Data Connection and then open tables and count, or just click on your X.edmx file, It's hard to understand what you mean withy our question clearify your question please

Comment: it's not equivalent with number of tables.